# load another html into div with jquery

Tags: jquery

can aynyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? The demo page, only with: "hello" word, cant show inside `#container`

```
<div id="galeria_oculta">
    <div id="container">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="#" id="exibe_galeria">click here</a>
</div>
```

here the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#galeria_oculta').hide();

    $('#exibe_galeria').click(function(e) {
        $('#galeria_oculta').show();
        $('#container').load('demo.html');
        e.preventDefault;
        return false;
    });

    $('#close_galeria').click(function(e) {
        $('#galeria_oculta').hide();
        e.preventDefault;
        return false;
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Can you please first tell us whats going wrong?

Comment: Well, the first problem would be: **not telling us what you want to do.**

Comment: yeah i forget that.. hehe sorry.. my DEMO.HTML page, is not loading inside `#container` div when i click on "CLICK HERE"

Comment: Any errors in your error console? And you don't need `e.preventDefault()` (note the parentheses) as well as `return false` (since `return false` combines [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and [`e.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)).

Comment: Can you log the status of the xhr request?

Comment: Have you successfully included the jQuery library on your page *before* your code?

Comment: David, no... only my #container going white, because is the color of the background...

Comment: look at: http://fakedc.com/teste/

on my demo page i used jqzoom example... if you access http://fakedc.com/teste/demo.html you see the content...

Comment: wow.. i see my error!!... i'm calling 2 times the jQuery library. One at my "click here" page, and second on demo.html.. sorry for that ppl...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
e.preventDefault;
```

is WRONG, correct is:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

maybe you called 2times the jQuery library :))))))))))))))))

Comment: i have some times this mistake.

Comment: While it's true that that's wrong, OP has still included `return false` which accomplishes the same thing (and more), and the `href` doesn't go anywhere anyway, so it shouldn't be the cause of the issue..

Comment: if write e.preventDefault;
it had syntax error and no other script code doesnt work!

Comment: Why would that be a syntax error? It's perfectly valid code. [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/h7rAv/)

Comment: @preston click on my answer as useful :))))))))))))

Comment: @EmRa228 hehehe ok.. but if i put `e.preventDefault();`i need to put too the `return false`?

Comment: @preston no,  you dont need it. e.preventDefault(); == return false